# Combined Chart Real-Time graph

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a little problem with real time combined chart by [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I had two different chart and it works in two single chart, but i would like to merge to one. The main problem is that there is nothing in the graph, when values incoming. I see ,that the references are okay.

Here is my code:

```
private void IntialcombinedChart(){
    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chartFetalandToco);

    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setNoDataText("No data yet");
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum((float)10);

    XAxis x1 = mChart.getXAxis();
    x1.setDrawGridLines(false);
    x1.setAxisMaxValue(1200);
    x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

    YAxis y1 = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    y1.setAxisMaxValue(255);
    y1.setAxisMinValue(0);
    y1.setDrawGridLines(true);


    YAxis y12 = mChart.getAxisRight();
    y12.setEnabled(false);


    cData = new CombinedData();

    cData.setData(new LineData());
    cData.setData(new ScatterData());
    mChart.setData(cData);
    mChart.invalidate();
}



public ScatterDataSet createFetalSet(){
    ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(null,"Fetal");
    set.setScatterShapeSize(7.5f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[2]);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    return  set;
}
 private LineDataSet createTocoSet(){
    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null,"Toco");
    set.setDrawCircles(false);
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[3]);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    return  set;


}

 public void AddFetalEntry(float sinValue){
    CombinedData data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        LineDataSet dataSetGraphA = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        ScatterDataSet dataSetGraphB = (ScatterDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(1);

        if (dataSetGraphA == null) {
            dataSetGraphA = createTocoSet();
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphA);
        }
        if (dataSetGraphB == null) {
            dataSetGraphB = createFetalSet();
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphB);
        }

        data.addXValue("");

        data.addEntry(new Entry(sinValue, dataSetGraphA.getEntryCount()), 0);

        data.addEntry(new Entry(sinValue, dataSetGraphB.getEntryCount()), 1);

        data.notifyDataChanged();


        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate(); // refresh

        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(2000);

        //int valueCount = data.getXValCount();
        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 2000);


    }
}
```

I think I wrote a good code, but it does not work. I try so many way to solave this, but I cant. I will be happy when to same value could appear on graph.

I hope, someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i spent more time to understand mpandroid chart system. First I created a empty scatterlinedata with dataset and a empty linedata with linedataset. After it I had to look for this chartdatas in combineddata,what I got from combined chart.

Here is my code:

```
private void IntialcombinedChart(){
    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chartFetalandToco);

    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setNoDataText("No data yet");
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum((float)10);

    XAxis x1 = mChart.getXAxis();
    x1.setDrawGridLines(false);
    x1.setAxisMaxValue(1200);
    x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);


    YAxis y1 = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    y1.setAxisMaxValue(255);
    y1.setAxisMinValue(0);
    y1.setDrawGridLines(true);


    YAxis y12 = mChart.getAxisRight();
    y12.setEnabled(false);

    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    cData = new CombinedData();

    cData.setData(generateLineData());
    cData.setData(generateScatterData());
    mChart.setData(cData);
    mChart.invalidate();




}
protected ScatterData generateScatterData() {

    ScatterData d = new ScatterData();


    d.addDataSet(createFetalSet());

    return d;
}

private LineData generateLineData() {
    LineData d = new LineData();
    d.addDataSet(createTocoSet());
    return d;
}
public ScatterDataSet createFetalSet(){
    ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(null,"Fetal");
    set.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[2]);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    return  set;
}

private LineDataSet createTocoSet(){
    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null,"Toco");
    set.setDrawCircles(false);
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[3]);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    return  set;


}
public void AddFetalEntry(float sinValue){
    fmDetected ++;
    CombinedData data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {


        ScatterData scatterDataData = data.getScatterData();
        if(scatterDataData != null){

            ScatterDataSet set = (ScatterDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
            if (set == null) {

                set = createFetalSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
            }
            scatterDataData.addXValue("");
            LineData tocoData = data.getLineData();
            if(tocoData != null) {

                LineDataSet pakk = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

                scatterDataData.addEntry(new Entry(sinValue,pakk.getEntryCount()-1), 0);
            }
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
        data.addXValue("");
        data.notifyDataChanged();


        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();
        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(1200);




        //int valueCount = data.getXValCount();
        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 7);
    }
}
public void AddTocoEntry(float sinValue){
    CombinedData data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {


        LineData tocoData = data.getLineData();
        if(tocoData != null){

            LineDataSet set = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
            if (set == null) {

                set = createTocoSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
            }
            tocoData.addXValue("");
            tocoData.addEntry(new Entry(sinValue,set.getEntryCount()),0);

            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
        data.addXValue("");
        data.notifyDataChanged();


        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();
        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(1200);




        //int valueCount = data.getXValCount();
        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 7);

    }
}
```

If someone could help me , that my code looks nicer, I would be very grateful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
ILineDataSet dataSetGraphA = (ILineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
IScatterDataSet dataSetGraphB = (IScatterDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
```

And initial the graph with actual data:

```
cData = new CombinedData();

cData.setData(generateLineData());
cData.setData(generateScatterData());
mChart.setData(cData);

private ScatterData generateScatterData() {

    ScatterData d = new ScatterData();

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(20, 15), index));

    ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "Scatter DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    set.setScatterShapeSize(7.5f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}

private LineData generateLineData() {

    LineData d = new LineData();

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(index + 0.5f, getRandom(15, 5)));

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setCircleRadius(5f);
    set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));

    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}
```

The rest of the code should be fine.